# New EC2 instances unreachable when deployed to Ireland

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am new in AWS. I have a few running EC2 instances in Virginia without any issue. Those where created mostly by previous sysadmin I only added 2 extra machines. Now I decided to start a few VMs in Ireland as well, but at the end of the process I can not reach them (ping, ssh etc).

As far as I can tell my settings are identical.

1. Created VPC
2. Created subdomain to VPC (auto public IP assign enabled)
3. Created elastic IP
4. Created Internet gateway attached to VPC
5. Created security group (1 rule: Enable All traffic on all ports from all IP address) --> I will restrict it but now I want to troubleshoot.
6. Created new key pair
7. Created new CentOS 7 with the above mentioned resources. (also tried with Ubuntu 14.04 same results)

First I tried to connect to the machine with the auto assigned IP with no luck. Then I attached the previously created elastic IP same results. Amazon "built in" status checks are green.

If I am deploying the same CentOS7 machine to East-US or Frankfurt I do not have this issue.

Is there any extra settings what I have to enable / create / pay to be able to run instances? Or is there any limit what I have to increase (I think I have default limits for everything)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I do missed out 1 of the steps. I had to create an extra route in the route tables. 0.0.0.0/0 <--> VPC

This happens when you do not read the X dozens pages of the getting started guide, and just want to do "something simple" fast.

Comment: There is nothing simple about getting started with AWS. It is very flexible, very powerful, but with those comes complexity. If you need only a single virtual machine, it's typically better to go with one of the more simple providers.

Comment: @itoperatorguy: I assume you mean you created a route to the IGW?

Answer (score 0):

The security group has settings for inbound and outbound traffic. Did you perhaps only allow outbound traffic to all IPs for all protocols and forgot to enable inbound traffic?
I am running several VMs in Ireland with elastic IPs and never had issues, except when the security rules were misconfigured (read: my local IP changed and I could not connect anymore).

Comment: Currently both inbound and outbound is enabled (all protocol, all port, all IP) This is why I don't know what I am missing.